# How to load magnific-popup's "ajax link" and "ajax linked pages content" in same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

When I click Magnific-Popup's ajax link then a loader is showing.
and then the loading screen hide and ajax Content Added but the page content completely not loaded.

linked pages content loading after the ajax popup show.

I want to load "ajax link" and "linked pages content" in same time.
when everything is loaded then popup should be show.
Is it possible?

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax'
});
```